# Extract an XML element value in shell script

Tags: xml, shell

I have something like below in my sample.xml file, and want to extract the value which is in **version** tag  only when the **artifactId** is **app1** as we would be having the multiple same set of tags with different **artifactId** in the given file using shell script.

```
<groupId>abc.app1</groupId>
<artifactId>app1</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>app1 ${version}</name>
<version>1.2.50</version>
```

My final output would be like below,

```
variable1=1.2.50
```

Note that I need to read a file and extract that string.

Comment: `only when the artifactId is app1 as we would be having the multiple same set of tags` so write code for that. You can use Python or Perl xml modules, there is xmllint and xmlstarlet. Shell has no XML support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For parsing xml files use xml parsers.

```
xmllint --xpath 'string(//version)' -
```

Comment: Or perhaps `//*[artifactId="app1"]/version` since the requirement was _only when the artifactId is app1_.

Answer (score 0):

Be carefull of XML pattern extract. It may become odd if the pattern is a hierarchy, and you may have to use XML dedicated libraries.

But, in your example, you may use a combination of grep and cut to extract your pattern:

```sh
cat $file | egrep '<version>' \
| cut '> -f 2 | cut '<' -f 1
```

Comment: The whole code (the fishing rod, the mealworm and even the fish) :
version=$( cat $file | egrep ''<version>' | cut '> -f 2 | cut '<' -f 1 | tail -n 1 ) ; echo "version=${version}"

Do not forget the "tail", to ensure you only have one result, the first one, in case of multiple values (standard failure case that may be catastrophic in some situations)

Comment: Thanks @Gaetan, I tried the above as script file and getting given error.

#!/bin/bash
file=/tmp/path/my.xml
echo $file
version=$( cat $file | egrep ''<version>' | cut '> -f 2 | cut '<' -f 1 | tail -n 1 ) ; echo "version=${version}"

However this is failing with below error.

/tmp/path/my.xml
./test1.sh: line 4: version: No such file or directory
cut: '<': No such file or directory
version=